# Constraint's target problem

Tags: constraints, unity

I have two objects, human and fridge. I want open the door of the fridge with my human's hand. So... I need to do two different animations, one for the human and one for the fridge. But i got a problem.
My right hand have a "child of" constraint and it's target is my fridge door. But in my game I need separate the fridge and the human. But when I delete the fridge from my scene in the Blender, I lose the target.
How can I keep target even it doesn't exists? Or how can I set target in Unity for Blender's constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution it's a use the bake action. Just select your action, press spacebar and type "Bake animation" and then select "visual keying" and "clear constraints" parameters.